# Grouped alternating row colors with a variation

Tags: javascript, c#, php, logic

This is a simple logical problem but I am having a mental block. I have groups of rows as follows:
[image]

Observe the following:

- Group #1 has 2 records
- Group #2 has 2 records
- **Group #3 has 1 record**
- Group #4 has 2 records
- **Group #5 has 1 record**
- Group #6 has 2 records

I want each record in each group to have the same background color as the other records in the group, yet a different background color from the next grouping after it. So, what I am trying to achieve is:

- Both records in group 1 should have a **white** background color.
- Both records in group 2 should have a **gray** background color.
- The sole record in group 3 should have a **white** background color.
- Both records in group 4 should have a **gray** background color.

...and so forth. So instead of the typical alternating row colors in which each record's bgcolor alternates, I want each group's bgcolor to alternate, while the colors within each group stays consistent with each other.

My current logic does this:

```
if($gameID != $previousGameID)
    $rowColor = "#ffffff";
else
    $rowColor = "#F0F0F0";
```

Although that code is PHP, this question is not unique to PHP, it's just a logic problem, which is why I tagged this question with PHP, C#, and JS (3 languages I know). My code above is wrong because it causes the background color to *change for each record*, rather than *for each group of records*. The records in each group have the same gameID, and that gameID will be different from all other groups. So the gameID is part of the key to solving this little puzzle, but I can't get my head around the solution.

Note: You cannot assume that each grouping will have either 1 or 2 records. Although my example doesn't show it, on rare occasions there will be 3 records in a group (and all 3 in that case would have the same gameID as each other).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the current logic is that you always change `$rowColor`, even when `gameID` hasn't changed.

Create an `alternateColor()` function that, when invoked, changes `$rowColor` between gray and white.

Then update you condition to

```
if($gameID != $previousGameID)
    alternateColor();
```

and then use the updated `$rowColor`.

This solution will work for any type of IDs (number, string etc.). A simple case would be that of numeric sequential IDs, that is: 1, 2, 3 etc. In this case the logic could be:

```
if ($gameID % 2 == 0)
    $rowColor = "#ffffff";
else
    $rowColor = "#F0F0F0";
```

That is, based on the fact that an ID is odd or even, the corresponding color is picked.

*UPDATE*:

Regarding sequential IDs, I didn't imply your IDs were sequential. I implied that *if* they were, than the modulus solution would be enough. The `alternateColor()` function approach will work for any type of IDs.

As an example of `alternateColor()`, consider this (**C#**):

Inside the class where your logic is, create an instance method `AlternateColor`  AND make sure your `rowColor` variable is an instance-level variable:

```
private string rowColor == "#ffffff"; // let's start with white

private void AlternateColor()
{
    this.currentColor = this.currentColor == "#ffffff" ? "#F0F0F0" : "#ffffff";
}
```

Now every time you call `AlternateColor` it will alternate `rowColor` between the two colors. And this is done when the current `gameID` changes.

*UPDATE 2*:

Not sure about the correctness of the following PHP, but you should get the idea:

```
class Games {
  private var $rowColor;

  private function alternateColor(){
     $this->$rowColor = ($this->$rowColor == "#ffffff" ? "#F0F0F0" : "#ffffff");
  }

  public function theFuncWhereYouOutputTheTable(){
     ...

     if($gameID != $previousGameID)
         $this->alternateColor();

     // use $rowColor afterwards
     ...
  }

}
```

Comment: I'm not following. gameIDs are rarely in sequential order and sometimes there are gaps between them. They will always be the same within a group, but that is all. I didn't mean to imply in my screenshot that 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 are gameIDs -- they're not. I was just trying to illustrate that there are groupings. Can you give me an example of your `alternateColor()` function code, along with the param(s) that would be passed in? Thanks!

Comment: Yes that works, thanks so much for your clarified response. Though I'm still puzzled why making that switch in a function (treating the color as a global) is any different from doing it inline, conditional on the gameid check. Obviously your way works and mine didn't, but I'm still puzzling why.

Comment: You're welcome. As to why this is different, and to elaborate on the 1st line of my answer, the correct logic is _if gameID changes, then use a different color, otherwise keep using the current color_, whereas the logic you had was _if gameID changes, then use one color, otherwise use another color_. In other words, had you a group with 3 or more games, you'd have seen that the 1st game has one color and ALL others in the group have another one.

Answer (score 1):

set a global variable to store the first color, say $rowColor= "#ffffff".
Then in loops

```
if($gameId != $previousGameId)
{
    alternateColor();
}
```

then define,

```
function alternate()
{
    if($rowColor== "#ffffff")
    {
         $rowColor= "#FOFOFO";
    }
    else
    {
         $rowColor= "$ffffff";
    }
}
```

This should work!!